# Extract ip address from a string using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
 var r = "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"; //http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

var a = "http://www.example.com/landing.aspx?referrer=10.11.12.13";

var t = a.match(r); //Expecting the ip address as a result but gets null
```

The above is my code to extract ip address from a string.
But it fails to do so.
Kindly advice where it fails.

Comment: wont lastIndexOf("=") + 1 subStr do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have defined `r` as string, initialize it as regular expression.

```
var r = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/;
```

```js
var r = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/; //http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

var a = "http://www.example.com/landing.aspx?referrer=10.11.12.13";

var t = a.match(r);
console.log(t[0])
```

Comment: the number should in between 0-255

Comment: ^ that is not a restriction you want to try to put in via a regex.