# Ansible way to just register the ip numbers

Tags: regex, ansible

Given the below string

```
fepv-lnxiaas-s4.fepoc.com has address 172.29.166.5
```

Need to remove

```
fepv-lnxiaas-s4.fepoc.com has address
```

and just keep

```
172.29.166.5
```

as a registered variable in Ansible. Need help with:

- proper regex replace code, or
- other method.

Comment: Hi. Welcome here. If you want to do this natively with Ansible, have a look at the [facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) functionality. With Linux commands, there are many possibilities, but piping the output of your command to `awk` to "print" the relevant field would also do.

Comment: Your question is unfocused. You can ask regex questions here, but ansible configuration questions are off-topic. Your question seems to be asking about regex and ansible configuration at the same time. It's not clear which one you are having a problem with. If it's regex you want help with then please remove any mention of ansible and specify clear requirements for the regex. Most likely, it would be a duplicate question though.

Comment: See this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689442/extract-ip-address-from-a-string-using-regex

Comment: This question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is `a specific programming problem` (regex replace code) or `a software algorithm`(other method) practical, answerable problem. The question is [mre] complete. 1) Minimal: Use as little code as possible. (The command is all you need) 2) Complete: Provide all parts. (stdout and expected result are all you need).

Answer (score 1):

The below *regex_replace* gives what you want

```yaml
  ip1: "{{ s|regex_replace('(.*) (.*)', '\\2') }}"
```

A simpler option might be to *split* the string and get the last item. The below declaration gives the same result

```yaml
  ip2: "{{ s|split|last }}"
```

You can use the *split* method instead of the filter

```yaml
  ip2: "{{ s.split()|last }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    s: fepv-lnxiaas-s4.fepoc.com has address 172.29.166.5
    ip1: "{{ s|regex_replace('(.*) (.*)', '\\2') }}"
    ip2: "{{ s|split|last }}"
    # ip2: "{{ s.split()|last }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ip1

    - debug:
        var: ip2
```

Comment: not able to use split function, running an older version of ansible

Comment: Use the *split* method. I added an example.